# Why would you call a function inside an addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I want to know the logic of a function inside of an addEventListener

I am reading through a very complex Javascript book. I'm on Chapter 7, Binding Events. It is explaining what it looks like to call a function inside of addEventListener. What is the purpose of calling the funtion inside of the EventListener ?

```
var btn = document.getElementByID

btn.addEventListener("click",function()
{
alertmessage("clicked the button");
},false);
```

Comment: To invoke that functionality when the event is triggered...  I guess it's not really clear to me what exactly the issue is here or what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

addEventListener, what it does it is behaving like a callback a call back function , like after clicking the particular item that has been clicked run the function under the hood .
It basically means when one has clicked or targeted something only then the inside function will run.

Its behaviour is same as call back functions .
Go through those once .